# VSCode with rust-analyzer, jump to first error after `cargo run` automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Coming from IDEA, I'm used to having the IDE jump to the first error in the build results after running a build command. In this case I want it for `cargo run`.

Is this possible in VSCode with the rust-analyzer plugin?

I looked through the settings, searched online, and even asked ChatGPT. Nothing really of note to get this working.

The best I can do is go into "Problems" (CTRL-SHIFT-M) and go to the next problem (F8), which currently *doesn't seem to go to the first error, just the first problem*.

Comment: What about using the filtering functionality of the problems panel? You can filter it by problem type (error, warning, info, etc.)

Comment: @user I did try that and F8 still goes to warnings, even when filtered out in the Problems panel.